# Is it possible to sort records by a temporary field in SOLR?

Tags: java, sorting, solr, enums

It's something interesting!.

I'm trying to explain my use cases so please let me know if you have any queries so I can clarify in the comment.

**Problem:**

Consider we have an `Employee` entity and also consider that we have a field like `Designation` (Enum value as described below) along with other fields of `Employee`. I'm displaying the list of Employee records in UI and there is functionality to do sort by the field Designation. Actually, I'm sorting records by the enum number of `EmpDesignation` which is resulting with incorrect order in the UI because I'm displaying Designation as Text (`SOFTWARE ENGINEER, WEB DEVELOPER, TECHNICAL SUPPORT, etc`) but sorting the records by the enum number which is the root cause for this issue.

```
enum EmpDesignation {
  SOFTWARE_ENGINEER = 0; 
  WEB_DEVELOPER = 1;
  TECHNICAL_SUPPORT = 2;
  NETWORK_ENGINEER = 3;
  BUSINESS_ANALYST = 4;
}
```

I'm looking for a `solution`/`approach`/`suggestion` to do sort records correctly by the text which I'm displaying in the UI. Please find the consider below notes too.

- I can't change the order of the Enum values as there are huge functionalities that are done based on the enum name and its number.
- I can't index the enum name as it will be required to do reindex the value every time based on some configuration around my application.
- I'm exploring about something like below.

  - creating a temporary field
  - Defining text values for each Designation enum numbers
  - Sorting by the defined text

Comment: You should be able to use `map` - I think you can return a textual value as the last term. However, be aware that sorting on a resolved field like that will be a lot less effective than just indexing it. I'm not sure that the data would change quickly enough to not warrant indexing it, seeing as a reindex usually will be a rather efficient process (and you can use atomic updates as necessary).

Comment: @MatsLindh, Thanks for your time. I'm not sure where I can use a map. Yes, I agree the point ` be aware that sorting on a resolved field like that will be a lot less effective than just indexing it`. I'm not going to index any new field and I'm trying to fetch the results by the same enum number value and sorting by the text values of that enum.

Comment: Best guess is to use something like `sort=map(map(field, 1, 1, 'WEB_DEVELOPER'), 0, 0, 'SOFTWARE_ENGINEER'))` - i.e. a recursive map that looks up each value. I understand what you're trying to do, it'd just be far better to index that field directly into Solr. If what the enum values mean changes, you'd still need to change the enum values indexed to represent the same thing.

Comment: Sure @MatsLindh. Thank you, my friend. I will try with the `map`. but As I mentioned in the description `I can't index the enum name as it will be required to do reindex the value every time based on some configuration around my application.`

Comment: I know. I'm saying that in many cases (from experience) that is is still desirable to do so, unless the configuration for some reason changes every couple of seconds. And if the semantic definition of the enum changes, then you'd need to reindex anyway (since 2 in existing documents no longer means what it used to mean).

Comment: Yes, you are correct.